# How to install laravelcollective/html in Laravel 7.4

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Running

```
 composer require laravelcollective/html
```

as in documentation, generates this error:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v7.4.0, required as 6.7.0) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - facade/ignition 2.0.2 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.4.0, 7.x-dev], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0].
    - facade/ignition 2.0.2 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.4.0, 7.x-dev], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0].
    - facade/ignition 2.0.2 requires illuminate/support ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.4.0, 7.x-dev], illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.7.0, 7.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.7.0, v7.4.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v7.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 6.7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.7.0].
    - Installation request for facade/ignition (locked at 2.0.2) -> satisfiable by facade/ignition[2.0.2].
```

Does it mean this package no longer works with Laravel?
What does this dump mean?

Is there a workaround?

Is there another package or should I just write HTML forms manually?

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "graham-campbell/markdown": "^12.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "6.7.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"

    },
    "require-dev": {

    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the laravel framework required as version 6.7 in your composer file, update that to 7.x

Comment: php artisan --version gives :Laravel Framework 7.4.0

Comment: Yes you have it installed at 7.4 but your composer.json file is *requiring* it at 6.7. This, not anything to do with Collective HTML (which works with 7) is causing your problem. Composer is trying to downgrade to 6.7 because thats what your composer.json file is telling it to do, but can't because facade/ignition requires 7.x, and it can't resolve that conflict. Change the laravel/framework line in composer.json to "^7.0" and run composer update, then try to install collective/html

Comment: That was the case! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your composer.json require {"laravelcollective/html": "^6.2",}

i.e for version 7 of laravel and run

composer install or composer update.

You should be good to go.