# How to solve Guzzle Error in Laravel during package installation

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, guzzle

trying to install the package but showing guzzle error problem 1  and currently project requirement is

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.6",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "php-http/curl-client": "^2.1"
    }, 

 Problem 1
    - Installation request for edujugon/laravel-google-ads ^1.2 -> satisfiable by edujugon/laravel-google-ads[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.10, 1.2.11, 1.2.12, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2.8, 1.2.9].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.x-dev, 7.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.1, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.x-dev, 7.0.1].
    - Conclusion: install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.x-dev
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 7.0.1, required as ^7.0) -> edujugon by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.1].
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is allow for 6.5

> "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5|^7.0.1",

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Laravel required `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"`, but your package want `6.5`. You need to create issue [here](https://github.com/Edujugon/laravel-google-ads/issues)

Comment: Also, https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib is the root of the Guzzle requirement so an issue here might be more effective