# Problems with composer update command

Tags: laravel, composer-php

composer update

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.29.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.29.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.29.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.29.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.30.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravelium/sitemap[8.0.1, ..., 8.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v4.0.0-BETA2, ..., 4.2.x-dev, v5.4.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7.29 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires laravelium/sitemap 8.* -> satisfiable by laravelium/sitemap[8.0.1, 8.x-dev].
```

As Im new to Laravel (and composer) I dont understand what it means, can you help please ?

Comment: try adding php version in composer.json  "php": "^7.3|^8.0",

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Comment: ` illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3`  - anything unclear about this?

Comment: I tried but still not working

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried"?

Comment: I did what he said and have still the same error with         "php": "^7.3|^8.0", And I dont have a line named illuminate/support in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Just check the details given in the error message:

```
    - laravelium/sitemap[8.0.1, ..., 8.x-dev] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[dev-master, v4.0.0-BETA2, ..., 4.2.x-dev, v5.4.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7.29 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires laravelium/sitemap 8.* -> satisfiable by laravelium/sitemap[8.0.1, 8.x-dev].
```

In your own `composer.json`, you require Laravel v7 and `laravelium/sitemap` in version `8.*`. That sitemap package in that version requires Laravel v8. As it is not possible to use two different versions of the same package in the same application, an error is thrown.

---

Possible solutions:

- upgrade `laravel/framework` from `^7.29` to `^8.0` (check the upgrade notes for this!)
- downgrade `laravelium/sitemap` from `8.*` to `7.*`