# I want to install composer require laravelista/comments but I get an error

Tags: composer-php, comments, laravel-7

I have php verison "PHP 7.4.27", composer version "2.2.4" and laravel version"4.2.9". And my error messages:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravelista/comments ^4.5 -> 
      satisfiable by laravelista/comments[4.5.0].
- laravelista/comments 4.5.0 requires illuminate/database ^8.0 -> 
      found illuminate/database[v8.0.0, ..., v8.79.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it 
      conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, 
  e.g. "composer require laravelista/comments:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or 
 "composer require laravelista/comments:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: You are using Laravel in version 1.5.0? If that even existed, it is horribly outdated. The oldest version available through Packagist is v4 from 2013. Please share more details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Comment: I am so sorry , I wrote the wrong version. Version is 4.2.9 . I'm pretty newbie in this project. I want to upgrade, but I couldn't go above 4.2.9 in my currently running project, despite updating laraveli. And is it a correct approach to use laravelista/comment system now?

Comment: Laravel 4.2.9 is more than seven years old. It requires Symfony packages that are out of support since years. Even the very first version of `laravelista/comments` available on Packagist requires Laravel 5.2 You should start to upgrade that first before adding new components to your application