# Working with Laravel Project without Vendor Folder

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I just downloaded a folder of Laravel Project from a server without vendor folder.
then tried to run composer install command to retrieve the vendor folder.
but an error message was shown in console.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module could not be found))
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module could not be found))
> in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
> library 'curl' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could
> not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found))
> in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
> library 'fileinfo' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified
> module could not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The
> specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be
> found), \xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
> to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\gettext (The
> specified module could not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_gettext.dll
> (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_gettext.dll (The specified module could not be
> found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\mbstring (The
> specified module could not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll
> (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be
> found), \xampp\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
> to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\exif (The
> specified module could not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll (The
> specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll (The specified module could not be found))
> in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
> library 'mysqli' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module
> could not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified
> module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be
> found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The
> specified module could not be found), \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll
> (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be
> found), \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
> to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite
> (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be
> found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be
> found), \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
> to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be
> found), \xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module
> could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not
> be found),  \xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified
> module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP
> Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll' (tried:
> \xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be found),
> \xampp\php\ext\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be
> found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll'
> (tried: \xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be
> found), \xampp\php\ext\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  Cannot open
> "\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini" for reading in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot open "\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini" for reading in
> Unknown on line 0 PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start standard module in
> Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unable to start standard module in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of the required plugins missing. You'll need to enable all of those DLLs in your xampp configuration.

Comment: please could you help me more? how to install them

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used xampp in years. I remember them being somewhere in the settings or php.ini.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Answer (score -1):

Php extensinos are not installed in your machinge, you can install php extension in linux with apt-get install

For example, if your Php version is 8.1,

```
sudo apt-get install php@8.1-bz2 

sudo apt-get install php@8.1-mbstring
```

In Windows OS you can enable the Php extensions from .ini file.

Comment: please can you further explain the Windows OS Example? I have a xampp program