# Installation error on laravel shopify osiset

Tags: laravel, shopify

I'm trying to create a laravel app on shopify but when I tried to run the command

```
composer require osiset/laravel-shopify
```

it returns error, the error says:

> Problem 1
>
> - Root composer.json requires osiset/laravel-shopify ^17.1 -> satisfiable by osiset/laravel-shopify[v17.1.0, 17.1.x-dev].
> - osiset/laravel-shopify[v17.1.0, ..., 17.1.x-dev] require laravel/framework ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> found laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.2).
>
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require osiset/laravel-shopify:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require osiset/laravel-shopify:^2.1" if you know which you need.

thank you for helping me

Comment: take a breather. now back to your error message. you can see an interesting words there "...but it conflicts with your root `composer.json` require `(^9.2)`." basically it says, your laravel version is 9.2, but the package need at a minimum version 7 and at maximum version 8.

Comment: How can I downgrade my laravel 9.2 to 8?

Comment: i wouldn't suggest downgrading, you should create a new laravel project with laravel version 8, see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#installation-via-composer).

Comment: I've encountered an error says 'Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.'

Comment: huh, hang on, may i know your php version and the command you entered?

Comment: I run this: 'composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app' but I have 'PHP 8,.1.1'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app "8.*"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:
I was also facing the same issue. I was trying to install it on laravel 10.42.0. I used the command

```
composer require osiset/laravel-shopify
```

but it gave below error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v0.1.0, ..., v0.1.1, v1.0.0, ..., v1.2.0] require laravel/framework 5.4.* -> found laravel/framework[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v1.3.0, ..., v1.3.1, v2.0.0] require laravel/framework ~5.5.0 -> found laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.50] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v2.0.1, ..., v2.3.2, v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.0, v4.0.0, ..., v4.3.0] require laravel/framework ~5.5 -> found laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.38] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v5.0.0, ..., v5.3.0, v6.0.0, v7.0.0, ..., v7.1.1, v8.0.0, ..., v8.0.1, v9.0.0, ..., v9.2.0] require laravel/framework ~5.6 -> found laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.38] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v1.0.1, v3.0.3, v5.3.1, ..., v5.4.0, v6.1.0, ..., v6.1.3] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.2).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v10.0.0, ..., v10.3.1] require laravel/framework ~5.6 | ^6.0 -> found laravel/framework[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.38, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v11.0.0, ..., v11.5.0, v12.0.0, ..., v12.1.0] require laravel/framework ~5.8 | ^6.0 | ^7.0 -> found laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.38, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v13.0.0, ..., v13.1.0, v14.0.0, ..., v14.0.3, v15.0.0, ..., v15.1.1] require laravel/framework ~5.8 || ^6.0 || ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> found laravel/framework[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.38, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v16.0.0, ..., v16.0.6, v17.0.0, ..., v17.1.1] require laravel/framework ^7.0 || ^8.0 -> found laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - osiset/laravel-shopify[v17.2.0, ..., v17.3.2] require laravel/framework ^7.0 || ^8.0 || ^9.0 -> found laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.16] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.10).
    - Root composer.json requires osiset/laravel-shopify * -> satisfiable by osiset/laravel-shopify[v0.1.0, v0.1.1, v1.0.0, ..., v1.3.1, v2.0.0, ..., v2.3.2, v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.0, v4.0.0, ..., v4.3.0, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.0, v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.3, v7.0.0, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v9.0.0, v9.1.0, v9.2.0, v10.0.0, ..., v10.3.1, v11.0.0, ..., v11.5.0, v12.0.0, v12.0.1, v12.1.0, v13.0.0, v13.1.0, v14.0.0, v14.0.1, v14.0.2, v14.0.3, v15.0.0, v15.1.0, v15.1.1, v16.0.0, ..., v16.0.6, v17.0.0, ..., v17.3.2].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require osiset/laravel-shopify:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require osiset/laravel-shopify:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

If we closely look at the error it is simply telling us which laravel-shopify version is compatible with which laravel version and it also finds that version, but unfortunately there is no laravel-shopify version compatible with my laravel version 10.42.0 (which is latest till now), so it is asking for a downgrade in laravel version.

So, I installed laravel 9.52.16 using command below:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^9.0 laravel9
```

then I ran

```
 composer require osiset/laravel-shopify
```

command again inside laravel9 directory (which is laravel root directory) and it worked like a charm.

Hope that will help.
Thanks!