# Issue when installing composer on Ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, server, composer-php

I Want to install laravel app and I user composer like this to install packages

```
composer install
```

And I get this error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/dbal 3.3.5 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[3.3.5].
    - doctrine/dbal 3.3.5 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I search any solution on the web without succes.

I'm on ubuntu server 20.04

Thank you

Comment: Make sure you have composer version ^2 installed. https://blog.laravel.com/upgrading-to-composer-v2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Comment: Thank very much for your links. None of them resolves my problem but i finaly found a solution specifilly for ubuntu using this link  because It seems like the way you install cmposer v2 in debian is different: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-composer-on-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

you have to upgrade the composer to version ^2.

run this command before "composer install"

=> composer self-update --2

Comment: Done. It save me