# Laravel firebase sync cannot install via composer

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, composer-php

I am using laravel framework with firebase database and i connected those two by using some package it's working fine ,now what my requirement is  i want to use eloquent models for manipulating data (model base queries and migration tables)for that i am installing following package

```
https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync
```

while installing this package i am getting following error can you please explain how to resolve this error

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.83.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.83.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.82.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.81.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.80.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.79.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.78.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.78.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.77.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.77.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.76.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.76.1
    - Installation request for mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync ~1.0 -> satisfiable by mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync[1.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.76.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.75.0
    - mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync 1.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^8.75 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v8.75.0, v8.76.0, v8.76.1, v8.76.2, v8.77.0, v8.77.1, v8.78.0, v8.78.1, v8.79.0, v8.80.0, v8.81.0, v8.82.0, v8.83.0, v8.83.1, v8.83.10, v8.83.11, v8.83.12, v8.83.13, v8.83.14, v8.83.2, v8.83.3, v8.83.4, v8.83.5, v8.83.6, v8.83.7, v8.83.8, v8.83.9].
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "kreait/laravel-firebase": "^4.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: The error message, even though you've only included half of it, seems very clear. The package you're trying to install is outdated and doesn't support modern versions of Laravel. You can't use it. `mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync 1.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)