# cannot running to Authentication error: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to make the authentication process to login and register but I can't because the error is like this.

[image]
I've also run composer update and it doesn't affect. Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Here is my composer.json look like.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

what's wrong with my project? how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share your composer.json file as well. Also quick reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log

Comment: Try `composer require laravel/breeze:1.10 --dev` basically the latest versions of those packages require Laravel 9 to work and you have laravel 8 so you need to specify versions that work with Laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the version of Laravel. Try installing the breeze as a separate package using the command "composer require laravel/breeze"