# A fresh Laravel install with Breeze to scaffold Vue & Inertia is throwing errors

Tags: laravel, vue.js, breeze

I have set up a brand new Laravel application and now I want Breeze to scaffold Vue & Inertia by executing this command, as explained in the official documentation: **php artisan breeze:install vue --ssr**

Besides of a couple of deprecation notices, I receive the following error messages:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

- laravel/framework is locked to version v10.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- laravel/framework v10.8.0 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found
  composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.

**Problem 2**

- laravel/framework v10.8.0 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- spatie/laravel-ignition 2.1.0 requires illuminate/support ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.8.0].
- spatie/laravel-ignition is locked to version 2.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Searching this channel has led to a couple of suggestions:

- composer self-update
- composer clearcache
- removing the composer.lock file

But none of them have solved my problem. So what is the real issue here and how can I solve it?

Comment: After updating composer, did you re-create your app, e.g., re-run *php artisan breeze:install vue --ssr*?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yes, with the same result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Comment: If you had *actually* run the `composer self-update` command you would not be getting `found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0]` in your output. Your version of composer is old, and needs updating.