# Issue to install doctrine/dbal in laravel 10.34.2

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-10

About three weeks earlier I set up a fresh project with Laravel and here I was also able to install doctrine/dbal later. Now I created another project yesterday evening and here doctrine/dbal can no longer be installed - do you have an approach here?

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires doctrine/dbal ^3.7 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2].
    - nesbot/carbon 2.72.0 requires carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types * -> satisfiable by carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types[3.0.0].
    - laravel/framework v10.34.2 requires nesbot/carbon ^2.67 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[2.72.0].
    - carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.7.2.
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v10.34.2 and an update of this package was not requested.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require doctrine/dbal:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require doctrine/dbal:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

Greetings
Tobias

I tried to install doctrine/dbal in laravel 10.34.2

Comment: "I tried to install doctrine/dbal in laravel 10.34.2" - what's the reason for this? Are you sure that DBAL wasn't installed before? Also, "carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types 3.0.0 conflicts with doctrine/dbal 3.7.2" is pretty clear: you can't use `carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types` in v3 with DBAL v3

Comment: Can you share your composer.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Comment: I got the same problem on Laravel 9 after updating... @NicoHaase - Your comment is not helpfull, since `carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types`is a sub-dependency on `nesbot/carbon` and `DBAL` is required by laravel for some migrations. 

@T. Poeschl: If you find a fix for this - please provide.

Comment: Feel free to require `carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types` in v2 (which is compatible with DBAL). Also, if `doctrine/dbal` is already required, why do you need to require it again?

Comment: @Husky110 yes i will provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have to install specific version of

```
composer require carbonphp/carbon-doctrine-types:^2.1.0
```

and then

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

this command will install the latest version (3.7)