# how downgrade php version to solve this error?

Tags: laravel

```
 Problem 1
    - spatie/pdf-to-image v2.x-dev requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - spatie/pdf-to-image 2.2.0 requires ext-imagick * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's imagick extension.
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/pdf-to-image ^2.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/pdf-to-image[2.2.0, v2.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-imagick` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

how to solve this error ,this error happen when i clone project laravel into local

Comment: You need the `imagick` PHP extension installed. Don't downgrade PHP.

Comment: Your [spatie/pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) dependency must be out-of-date too since the current version definitely supports PHP v8.x

Comment: how to install imagick extension,i use laragon for host

Comment: @Shah I don't use Laragon, but Googling "laragon imagick" comes up with fairly clear instructions. https://github.com/leokhoa/laragon/discussions/424

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Screenshot]

Switch php version here.
You can also see extension installation.

Vagrant + homestead may be a better choice for laravel development. The integrated environment includes commonly used extensions and configurations.It is an environment similar to a server, not a windows environment