# trying to install phhp spreadsheet but when doing so i get the following output in CMD

Tags: php, composer-php

> C:\xampp>composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd
> Cannot use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet's latest version 2.0.0 as it requires ext-fileinfo * which is missing from your platform.

> In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 318:

> Package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet has requirements incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 2.0.0 requires ext-fileinfo * but it is not present.
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 2.0.0 requires ext-gd * but it is not present.
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 2.0.0 requires ext-zip * but it is not present.

> require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [...]

Comment: `ext-fileinfo` is a PHP extension. You have to enable that in your `php.ini` file

Comment: So are `ext-gd` and `ext-zip`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: im a newbie in development so im unable to understand how to do that please explain in a bit detail how caan i resolve this issue please!! and im unable to find any php.ini file its showing php.ini-development

Comment: edit your `php.ini` find the sections where all the `extension` commands are, you will see these 3 extensions mentioned, example `;extension=fileinfo` remove the `;` to uncomment that extension and make it active. Do that for all 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini

Comment: i removed those semicolons(;) from those 3 extensions still the output is same it is showing the same error even now...!!

Comment: how worse? did you restart apache?

Comment: yes i did that but still the output is same idk what's the issue here

Comment: c:\xampp>composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
Cannot use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet's latest version 2.0.0 as it requires ext-fileinfo * which is missing from your platform.

In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 318:

  Package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet has requirements incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer v
  ersion:
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 2.0.0 requires ext-fileinfo * but it is not present.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 2.0.0 requires ext-gd * but it is not present.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 2.0.0 requires ext-zip * but it is not present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Composer's error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073506/how-to-explain-composers-error-log)

Comment: so if you are running Composer you are using the PHP CLI. I cannot remember if the `php.ini` for XAMPP is the same for Apache and CLI. Run this from the command line  `>php --ini` and look at the output for the line titled `Loaded Configuration File:` check that you are editing that `php.ini` file